# Can we not run BTSHTTPReceive.dll in Win XP (IIS 5)

Tags: biztalk

I am trying to run the sample of Biztalk Samples\AdaptersUsage\HTTPRequestResponse in my machine where bizTalk is properly setup. Being Windows XP, it has IIS 5.1 and in the tutorial (ms-help://MS.BTS.2006/BTS06CoreDocs/html/81c66f61-d86c-49cf-8d24-21c67c68bc5a.htm) it is written in the 3rd step to create the application pool, but there is no concept of application pool in IIS 5. Is it not possible to run this tutorial in win xp?

If not, can i not run biztalk application to communicate with web service too in windows xp machine?

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow slightly different procedure to configure IIS 5.0,  you need to set your virtual directory isolation level to either medium or high and setup the identity using component service.

See the link for detailed steps

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559072.aspx

Saravana Kumar [MVP- BizTalk Server]
http://www.biztalk247.com/v1/
http://blogs.digitaldeposit.net/saravana